# How to plot square using Algebraic function

Tags: analytic-geometry

I want to plot Square, i have 1 equation which plot square but in diagonal form(Like Diamond Shape),

```
plot r = 1/(cos(mod (t, PI/2))+sin(mod (t, PI/2))), t = 0 .. 2*PI
```

Live Demo [Diamond Square](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20r%20%3D%201%2F%28cos%28mod%20%28t%2C%20PI%2F2%29%29%2Bsin%28mod%20%28t%2C%20PI%2F2%29%29%29%2C%20t%20%3D%200%20..%202*PI)

Please let me know how to change this equation so that it will plot square box instead of diamond shape.

Please edit this if i miss to be mention or wrong tag this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> plot r = 1/(cos(mod (t+PI/4, PI/2))+sin(mod (t+PI/4, PI/2))), t = 0 .. 2*PI

See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r+%3D+1%2F%28cos%28mod+%28t%2BPI%2F4%2C+PI%2F2%29%29%2Bsin%28mod+%28t%2BPI%2F4%2C+PI%2F2%29%29%29%2C+t+%3D+0+..+2*PI).

This square goes through the axes at $\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$.  If you want to make that $\pm1$ instead, change the numerator in the plot command to $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks, It's Works Perfectly..

Comment: What will be the formula for a rectangular shape?

Comment: Can't think of any easy modification of your method.  Maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

r = 1/cos(0.25arccos(cos(4x))

might be simpler but yh

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r+%3D+1%2Fcos%280.25arccos%28cos%284x%29%29

Answer (score 0):

Center: $(a\mid b)$ .
Corner 1: $(a+c\mid b+d)$ .
Corner 2: $(a-d\mid b+c)$ .
Corner 3: $(a-c\mid b-d)$ .
Corner 4: $(a+d\mid b-c)$ .